# Seeking open source linux tools for distributed task management

Tags: linux, service, ipc

We have an architecture with a couple hundred of servers with about 200 
processes  (all developed in-house) spread over them, some controlled
by crontab and some that run as daemons. Some servers are in 'groups'
where all servers are configured identically, and other servers have
custom configurations.  I've been tasked with centralizing the control
of these tasks.

One use case is that a user ssh'ed into any box must be able to control
any process on the network in something close to real time, by starting
and stopping the relevant daemon or rebuilding and reinstalling the 
crontab.  There are already various bits and pieces created to drive
all of this from a database, but the overall architecture hasn't been thought
through.

I'm expecting I'll write a daemon that will run on each server and 
mediate between peer-to-peer networking, the database and the daemons and 
crontabs.

I'm surveying what technologies might aid and abet this project.

I think I'm looking for peer-to-peer reliable communication technologies.
Though I'm not 100 percent sure that's what I need.  Things on my radar
include Spread, JXTA, Zookeeper and JMS.

What are people's experiences with these technologies, and what other
technologies should I check out?  As I see it, I'm going to have very
low data rates (a few thousand bytes per hour at most). But reliability
and a mature API are important.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not a really direct answer to any of your questions but stuff you describe sounds alot  like you will end up doing alot of duplicate work - specially if just thinking about the "user ssh's into one box" part. (pun unintentional but now that i noticed it, yey!=)

Have you taken a look in projects like http://www.cfengine.org or http://www.theether.org/pssh/ ?

Comment: We do already use cfengine for provisioning our servers. This effort is at a slightly higher level: Manipulating processes while the servers stay up. pssh is interesting, so thanks for the pointer, but is more a user-level tool. I need an API, plus built-in reliability.

Comment: You can use cfengine for ongoing configuration updates, without requiring reboots.  Although it's a lot of work.  I thought puppet looked good.  It's like cfengine, but let's you do some more stuff.  IIRC, it can look at the process table to check if something is running or not.